# "gameActivity" Key is changed at start but it should stop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm working on my DiscordBot right now. In the file bot.json is the key "gameActivity" which can be changed over the website... but when I start the bot this key will be deleted. Thanks in advance

**index.js**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('./botconfig.json');
const web_info = require('../data/bot.json')

bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.user.setActivity(web_info.gameActivity, { type: 'PLAYING' });

  console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);

  var webdata = {
    status: 'online'
  };

  let data = JSON.stringify(webdata);
  fs.writeFileSync('../data/bot.json', data);
  console.log(webdata);
});

bot.login(config.token);
```

**bot.json**

```json
{"status":"online","gameActivity":"This will be deleted!"}
```

**bot.json after starting the bot**

```json
{"status":"online"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is because `webdata` is only sending the status and not the activity as well.

What you want this to look like is:

```
var webdata = {
    status: 'online',
    gameActivity: 'blah blah'

  };

  let data = JSON.stringify(webdata);
  fs.writeFileSync('../data/bot.json', data);
  console.log(webdata);
```

You can replace "blah blah" with whatever you want.

Hopefully, this helped,
Chills.

Comment: Yes, I know that this works, but if I have changed it on the website and then I want to start the bot, the gameActivity key will be changed. But I want it to stay the same as I changed it on the website. Do you understand?

Comment: Alright, I understand but I am not that good with back end web stuff so I will have to leave this one. My apologies

Comment: yea i'm self not good at backend i only do frontend html and css :D

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a new object:

```js
web_info.status = 'online';

let data = JSON.stringify(web_info);
fs.writeFileSync('../data/bot.json', data);
console.log(webdata);
```

The `gameActivity` property is being removed, as you are creating a new object without that property and writing it back to the `bot.json` file. Either create a new object and set all properties or use and modify the original.